# Yandex Maps: при скролле страницы смещаются координаты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На странице размещена карта (Yandex Map), включена кластеризация пинов.

Изначально все нормально, при наведении на кластер над ним меняется курсор (становится pointer) и можно нажать - кластер раскрывается.

Но если проскроллить страницу (саму страницу, не карту), то местоположение кластера как будто "сползает" вслед за скроллом, при этом иконка остается там, где была.

При наведении на иконку кластера курсор не меняется, но если чуть ниже навести, то меняется и можно кликнуть и кластер открывается.

Если обратно отскроллить страницу, снова можно совместить зону клика и иконку кластера.

Также при двойном клике по карте происходит зум (как должно быть), но центр карты смещается не на место клика, а сдвигается. Сдвиг зависит от скролла тоже.

Повторить в песочнице не могу :(
Подскажите, в какую сторону можно посмотреть...

Comment: Для начала отключите CSS-фильтры и начните подключать поочереди. Скорее всего один из общих влияет на слой активных областей. Я бы решил, что слой попал под влияние position: absolute; или чего-то подобного. Без доступа к странице что-то более определённое сложно будет сказать.